# Return documents where sub-document field value like %text%

Tags: arrays, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use the `$in` to find content in MongoDB. Basically what in SQL will be `where name like '%text%'`

I have the following structure

```
{ 
    name: "Roger", 
    address: [
        { 
            street: "Upper Main Street", 
            number: 107 
        }
    ], 
    age: 70
}
```

I'm trying to find record where street like '%main%' and age <50

I tried the following:

```
db.collection.find(
    { $and: 
        [ street: { $in: [ /main/ ] } ], 
        [age: {$lt: 50}]
    }
   )
```

I don't manage to get the query work. I think it is because street is inside the address array, but I can not figure it out how to query inside this array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to address the "street" field. Also you don't need to use the [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) logical operator here as mentioned in the documentation.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

```
db.collection.find({ "address.street": /main/i, "age": { "$lt": 50  } })
```

You also don't need the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks for the solution and advice.